# Getting image url with rollup

Tags: rollup, rollupjs

In webpack I could do following

```
import imageSrc from 'some-node-module/img.png'

const <img src={imageSrc} alt="">
```

I would like to be able to do the same in rollup. I tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-img

I can get the image bu encoded. Fo my use case I need the actual url so the I can request it.

Comment: What is bu encoding? Maybe you mean base64?

Answer (score 0):

I found [@rollup/plugin-image](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rollup/plugin-image) to work.

It does, however, provide the images as `<img src="data:image/png;...." />` nodes. To my use, that is perfect.

Why do you want the actual URL?

Comment: My use case was to provide an url to an internal tracking framework. So its not for display. Thanks anyway.